# for loop only printing half the values (working with vectors)

Tags: c++, memory, dynamic, vector

The for loop in main that is suppose to pop_back the values is only printing half the values in the array. However, when i write (i <= user) it prints all the values.

MyVector.h

```
template<class T>
T MyVector<T>::Pop_back( ){
   return elements_ptr[--vectorSize];
   }
```

main.cpp

```
int main() 
{
    MyVector<int> v1;
    int user = 500;

    for(int i= 1; i <= user; i++){
         v1.Push_back(i);
    }
    cout << v1.size() << endl; // outputs 500

    for (int j = 0; j < v1.size(); j++){
         cout << v1.Pop_back() << " ";
         if( j % 20 ==0 ){
         cout << endl;
         }
   }

   return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
for (int j = 0; j < v1.size(); j++) { … }
```

As you continue to pop elements off your vector, its reported `size()` is getting smaller and smaller while `j` grows.  After you have popped half the elements, the loop condition becomes false.

The solution is to use either

```
while (v1.size()) { … }
```

or

```
const int N = v1.size();
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) { … }
```

as you've already found out.  I'd prefer the former.

Answer (score 2):

Every time you call `pop_back()` the value that `size()` returns reduces by 1.

So if you start with two elements in the vector and call `pop_back()` on the first iteration, on the second iteration you have `j == 1` and `size() == 1`, and therefore the loop exits without handling the second element.

Answer (score 2):

Because you're changing the size of vector (in `Pop_back()`) inside the for loop, which is used for the ending condition of the loop. Maybe you should store the size before the for loop.

```
int v1_size = v1.size();
for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
```